# How does Swagger achieve the same route but different query parameters?

Tags: asp.net-core, http, swagger

I created an asp.net core web api project, using the .net5 version, and I have a route like this.

```
[Route("api/detail")]
public IEnumerable<User> Get()
{
       //TODO
    return users;
}

[Route("api/detail")]
public IEnumerable<User> Get(string name)
{
        //TODO
    return users;
}
```

Although my request method is the same and the request parameters are different, the 500 error will be reported in swagger. Is there any way to solve it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "the 500 error will be reported" - that just means something went wrong on the server. It's up to you to get the actual exception details. Then if you can't resolve it, provide the details here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There could be multiple reasons why you're getting a 500 error. When I pasted your code into a new controller the first is error I received was:

> Ambiguous HTTP method for action... Actions require an explicit HttpMethod binding for Swagger

It's telling you that you need to decorate each action in the controller with an HttpMethod binding, like `[HttpGet]`. More on that in a second...

The next issue is that you're using `[Route]` to bind two different action methods to the exact same route with the same HttpMethod. That's not possible in an API controller.

> Conflicting method/path combination... Actions require a unique
> method/path combination for Swagger

My preferred method for routing is to use [Attribute routing with Http verb attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-with-http-verb-attributes).

The first step would be to move the route attribute to the controller. I'm going to assume you've created a `DetailsController`:

```cs
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class DetailsController : ControllerBase { }
```

Now, update your actions. Remove the `[Route]` attribute, replace with the `HttpGet` attribute, and add the `name` parameter to your second endpoint. I also prefer to return an `IActionResult`:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get()
{
    //TODO
    return Ok(users);
}

[HttpGet("{name}")]
public IActionResult Get(string name)
{
    //TODO
    return Ok(users);
}
```

Note that parameters are identified by using curly braces around the variable `{name}` in the Http method attribute. Both endpoints work and are accessible through swagger. I urge you to read the linked page above for a better understanding of the possible routing options ([linked again](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#attribute-routing-with-http-verb-attributes)).

[image: swagger endpoints]